# Is any instance/part of Windows running while Ubuntu Desktop on Wubi is running?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 to dual-boot using *Wubi*, so the system files are inside `C:\ubuntu` and, on boot, I can choose which OS to use.

Since the system files are located in the windows partition, is Windows (7) running in any way, somewhat like a virtual machine would? Or does Wubi and Ubuntu ignore the Windows operating system already installed on the `C:` drive?

Comment: The rest of the drive you are installed on *is* mounted and you can access files from it (they are in the /host folder). However I do not know about the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WUBI installs Ubuntu on a hard drive image on a Windows partition/file system. It is not a virtual machine, and windows is not in any way running when you boot that Ubuntu installation.